# How to format a table in C

Tags: c, arrays, unix, formatting

I am new in C, still trying to figure out some of the formatting stuff. I was wondering how would print an array giving it a specific number of columns and align the array elements to the right or left.

So if I use an integer array (one dimensional), how can I print the array in a table format with rows and columns?

Comment: I suggest a little research into format specifiers for `printf()`, for example `printf("%-8d", i);` will format an integer into the left of a field 8 characters wide.

Answer (score 1):

You read about the [printf formatting](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/printf-format-strings.html) and function reference. Take this code as an example and work your way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    enum alignment { RIGHT, LEFT};

    int tableAlignment = RIGHT;
    int i;
    int columnWidth = 5; // Set max column Width of Table
    int cellWidth = 11;  // Set Max Cell Width
    char cellFormat[10];
    int data[10] = { 1, 20, 300, 4000, 50000, 600000, 7000000, 80000000, 900000000, 1000000000};

    // Set Cell Alignment
    // Set cellWidth
    // Set data type according to the data
    if ( tableAlignment == RIGHT )
    {
        sprintf(cellFormat,"%%%s%d%s","",cellWidth,"d");
    }
    else if ( tableAlignment == LEFT )
    {
        // - for Left-justification
        sprintf(cellFormat,"%%%s%d%s","-",cellWidth,"d");
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Invalid Alignment");
    }
    printf("%s\n",cellFormat);
    for ( i = 1; i <= 10; ++i )
    {
        printf(cellFormat, data[i-1]);
        // break line reaching max columnWidth
        if ( ((i) % columnWidth ) == 0 ) printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could use `sprintf(cellFormat, "%%%dd", -cellWidth);` or the positive version to simplify the code that generates the format string.